# using fetching mode in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Let's say we have one to many relationship between Customer and Phone..

```
class Customer{

@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},mappedBy = "customer", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Fetch( FetchMode.SELECT)
private List<Phone> phoneList;

}
```

In the above code, what is the difference between 
fetch = FetchType.LAZY and  FetchMode.SELECT.

I read it that they both are same i.e. they both lazily loaded the underlying collection.

Can somebody explain me which one to use when?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fetch type (lazy/eager) refers to *when* Hibernate will fetch the association, whether in advance when it fetches the entity (eager), or whether it waits for the code to ask for the association (lazy).

Fetch mode (select/join) refers to *how* Hibernate will fetch the association, i.e. does it use an extra SELECT statement, or does it use a join.

Some combinations of these make no sense, e.g. lazy+join. If you use lazy fetching, then SELECT fetch mode is the only one that you can do.

If you use eager fetch, then you can choose to use either fetch mode.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.So in case of eager fetch, which fetch mode is better to use..SELECT or JOIN?

Comment: @anand: There is no "better", but if join works for you, it'll usually give better performance.